# Something wrong with git --format string in a batch file FOR /F loop?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

In a batch subroutine, I want to get the latest git date for a file.

So, inside the for loop, I get `fatal: bad revision` on the format, but when I execute the same command outside the loop, it works just fine. I also tried "usebackq" `` and get the same result.

```
set f=path/to/file.md

REM what I want to do...
for /f "delims=" %%p in ('git log -1 --format=^\^"%%ci^\^" -- %f%') do set g=%%p

REM test...
git log -1 --format=^\^"%%ci^\^" -- %f%
```

Result:

```
fatal: bad revision '"%ci"'
"2019-02-05 20:08:54 -0800"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Debug it by changing the line to `for /f "delims=!" %%p in ('echo log -1 --format=\"%ci\" -- %f%') do echo %%p`. That way you can see what command line got passed to git.

Comment: Why the ``\``? The command you want is: `git log -1 --format="%ci" -- %f%`, correct? (or even without the quotes).

Comment: There is no need to try to escape anything here, so no `^\^"`, no `\"`, just use `"` here... The question is: should `%%ci` be passed to the `git` command literally, or what else is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all escapes were not needed. The characters that need to be escaped are `` %^&<>|'`,;=() `` and they are escaped with the caret (`^`) except for `%` which is escaped with `%%`. Are there these characters in your command (`git log -1 --format="%ci" -- %f%`)?

Yes, the equal sign: `=`. You will need to modify your code as follows:

```
set "f=path/to/file.md"

REM what you want to do...
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('git log -1 --format^="%%ci" -- %f%') do set "g=%%A"
```

Even if you like to use `\` `*` `\`, you don't need to escape them.

Comment: Doh! Thanks so much! I should add that once I got it working I need to add "tokens=*", too, I'll edit both.

Comment: @arkadianriver, better to use `"delims="` instead of `"tokens=*"`.

Comment: But you forgot your own rule for doubling the percent sign. It should read `git log -1 --format^="%%ci" -- %f%`  or with quotes `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"git log -1 --format="%%ci" -- %f%"') do set "g=%%A"`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. one note.. for the quotes to show up in a subsequent echo (for use writing to a YAML file and not barfing on the colons), I need the backslashes on the quotation marks

Comment: I'm trying to get a similar for loop to work . . . FOR /F %%x IN ('git log -1 --format^="%%D" -- %TAG%') DO set OUTPUT=%%x
 echo %OUTPUT% . . . But I just keep getting "ECHO is off"